# measurement of tripartit qubit state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

From general schmidt decomposition, GSD, the state of tripartite is classify by five parameter as below:

|V>=a|000>+b|100>+c|110>+d|101>+e|111>.

how can I determine the value of parameter a,b,c,d,e?

It that the same way to determine the parameter for any state that differ from GSD?

I wonder how the value come from when given the state.

thank you for answering my question.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you talking about a quantum state made up of three qubits shared amongst three parties? Then where have the 001, 010, and 011 states gone? Why are you applying a schmidt decomposition, given that it only applies to states shared amongst two parties? What constraints are preventing you from just measuring a bunch of copies of the state to learn a, b, c, d, and e via tomography?